# When I am developing an Android application,how to set ListView not scrolling but,can Click and long Click

Tags: android, listview, scroll

When I am developing an Android application,how to  set that a  ListView  can not scroll，but it can be clicked and long clicked,thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable scrolling in ListView and keep it responding for clicking at the same time you need to override dispatchTouchEvent() method in your customListView as shown below:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
   if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
      return true;
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

or

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you ,I know how to solve  it

Answer (score 0):

If your list should not scroll use a ViewGroup like a `LinearLayout` and add all the items to this ViewGroup in a loop in your code. If you want a whole row to be clickable you have to use another ViewGroup as the root node for each row and add the `OnClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener` to this View.